# java time (Wed Feb 29 20:56:47 +0000 2012) to epoch

Tags: java, time, epoch

I have a database filled with timestamps in the following format:

```
Wed Feb 29 20:56:47 +0000 2012
Wed Feb 29 00:32:48 +0000 2012
Fri Apr 01 00:10:30 +0000 2011
```

I need to turn the into Epoch times to easily do calculations.

I want them to be seconds since 1970 (like what `System.currentTimeMillis()/1000` does)

Does java have some method for this or do I have to parse and calculate it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you want to perform these calculations? In your code or at the DB level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you have to parse it, but that's easy enough to do with [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy",
                                               Locale.US);

Date date = format.parse(text);
long secondsSinceEpoch = date.getTime() / 1000;
```

On the other hand, it would be better if you stored the values in your database in a more appropriate column type to start with. Are you *really* storing them as text? If so, why?

Comment: I just need a standard. Epoch seems like the easiest to use for me. I need to calculate time intervals and convert to different formats in different code languages.

Comment: @PatrickLorio: But why use *text* in the database at all? Surely your database has some sort of DATETIME field type, and even if it doesn't it would be much more efficient to just store the number of milliseconds or seconds since the epoch *as a number*. Why go through parsing and formatting all the time? (Note that with a non-text format, you'd be able to calculate time intervals *in SQL*, as well as performing comparisons for filtering etc.)

Comment: Sorry I don't think I properly answered you question. I will be storing the epoch times as numbers. I will only be formatting it once into the database. And for converting it into different formats will be on the client side. Also I won't be doing SQL operations, it's more just a place to store my data not crunch through it.

Comment: @PatrickLorio: But why bother storing it in text in the database at all? Why introduce conversions for no reason? Just keep it as "seconds the epoch" or a more strongly-typed value everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution using `java.time`, the modern API:

Your date-time string has timezone offset value and therefore, it's a candidate to be parsed into `OffsetDateTime` object which you can convert to `Instant`. The function, [`Instant#toEpochMilli`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toEpochMilli--) converts an instant to the number of milliseconds from the epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM d H:m:s X u", Locale.ENGLISH);
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("Wed Feb 29 20:56:47 +0000 2012", dtf);
        Instant instant = odt.toInstant();
        long epochSecond = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(instant.toEpochMilli(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        System.out.println(epochSecond);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1330549007
```

Try to avoid performing calculations yourself if you have standard API available (e.g. [`TimeUnit#convert`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#convert(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) used in the code above) to achieve what you would do with the calculation.

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>